# What is the correct method to use data connections in Microsoft Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm starting to use data connections in Microsoft Excel to an Oracle SQL database using ODBC. I'm confused as to the intended method of using data connections.

It appears as through a data connection is linked to a query, so if my workbook has 100 queries then I need to make 100 data connections. Is this correct or can you use a single data connection to perform multiple queries?

Answer (score 1):

If all the data is in one data source, you only need to make one connection. Multiple data sources would only be needed if the data you need is in separate databases.

Having a data connection allows you to query that source as much as you like. Keep in mind that performance will suffer the more queries you have refreshing from that source.

[Use Microsoft Query to retrieve external data](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-Microsoft-Query-to-retrieve-external-data-42a2ea18-44d9-40b3-9c38-4c62f252da2e)

[Create, edit, and manage connections to external data](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-edit-and-manage-connections-to-external-data-89d44137-f18d-49cf-953d-d22a2eea2d46)